# node.js promise.then() get excuted without all() fulfillment

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, web-crawler

I faced a problem when I wrote a **crawler** in **node.js**. The problem is that the `then()` of promise get executed once it was called, but not when the promise array `all()` return fulfillment.

I have been searching and trying to find the reason, but it seems that nobody has this problem before.

```
var http = require('https');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var url = 'https://developer.teamwork.com/';


function filterData(html) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    // console.log(html);
    // var data = {
    //     title: title,
    //     APIs: [{
    //         apiTitle: apiTitle,
    //         type: type,
    //         apiUrl: apiUrl,
    //         description: description,
    //         req: {
    //             description: description,
    //             content: {}
    //         },
    //         res: {
    //             description: description,
    //             content: {}
    //         }
    //     }]
    // };
    var title = $('.api--main').find('h2').text();
    console.log('|' + title + '|');

}


function filterModules(html) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var modules = $('.api--main').find('.lev1');
    // [{
    //     moduleTitle: '',
    //     moduleURL: ''
    // }]
    var modulesData = [];
    var module = '', moduleTitle = '', Url = '';
    modules.each(function (item) {
        module = $(this).find('a');
        moduleTitle = module.text();
        Url = module.attr('href');
        if (!Url.match('//')){
            moduleUrl = url + Url;
        } else {
            moduleUrl = Url;
        }
        modulesData.push({
            moduleTitle: moduleTitle,
            moduleUrl: moduleUrl
        });
    });

    return modulesData;
}

function printModuleInfo(data) {
    var moduleTitle;
    var moduleUrl;
    var printResults = '';
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        moduleTitle = item.moduleTitle;
        moduleUrl = item.moduleUrl;
        printResults = printResults + '<' + moduleTitle + '>\n' + '  URL: ' + moduleUrl + '\n';
    });
    return printResults;
}

function getContents(url,title) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        http.get(url, function(res) {
            console.log('crawling:'+url);
            var html = '';

            res.on('data', function(data) {
                html += data;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                resolve({
                    title: title,
                    html: html
                });
            });
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            reject(e);
        });

    });
}



var allOriContents = [];

http.get(url, function (res) {
    var html = '';
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        html += data;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        // console.log(html);
       var modulesData = filterModules(html);
        modulesData.forEach(function (item) {
            // console.log(item.moduleTitle);
            if (!(item.moduleTitle === 'Introduction')) {
                allOriContents.push(getContents(item.moduleUrl,item.moduleTitle));
                // console.log(allOriContents[0]);
            } else {}
        });
    });
}).on('error', function () {
    console.log('There are errors when getting urls.');
});
// setTimeout(function () {
    Promise
        .all(allOriContents)
        .then(function (obj) {
            console.log(obj.length);
            var modulesData = [];
            var module;
            var moduleData;
            obj.forEach(function (item) {
                console.log(item.title);
                module = filterData(item.html);
                moduleData = {
                    title: item.title,
                    data: module
                };
                modulesData.push(module);
            });
            modulesData.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.title < b.title;
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
// }, 120000);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your http.get is also an async call and by the time Promise.all(allOriContents) is being executed, it's likely that the allOriContents is empty.

Move your promise code to within res.end

```
res.on('end', function () {
        // console.log(html);
       var modulesData = filterModules(html);
        modulesData.forEach(function (item) {
            // console.log(item.moduleTitle);
            if (!(item.moduleTitle === 'Introduction')) {
                allOriContents.push(getContents(item.moduleUrl,item.moduleTitle));
                // console.log(allOriContents[0]);
            } else {}
        });
        Promise
    .all(allOriContents)
    .then(function (obj) {
        console.log(obj.length);
        var modulesData = [];
        var module;
        var moduleData;
        obj.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.title);
            module = filterData(item.html);
            moduleData = {
                title: item.title,
                data: module
            };
            modulesData.push(module);
        });
        modulesData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.title < b.title;
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    });
```

Comment: or you could also wrap your http.get in a promise and execute your promise.all code when that promise is resolved.

Comment: I didn't know http.get is also async, I will give it a try, thank you very much.